# How to expose the right listener for client (producer/consumer) connectivity?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm a little confused here at the moment. I'm working with Kafka v1.0 and it is being hosted in a VM in the cloud. The single VM hosts Zookeeper as well as Kafka.

I can't seem to get a `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` configuration for server properties figured out so I can connect remotely with my producer and consumers.

If I set it like this...

```
listeners=CLIENT://:9090,PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=CLIENT://:9090,PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

From my external client I get a `NoBrokersAvailable` error. If I try this...

```
listeners=CLIENT://0.0.0.0:9090,PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=CLIENT://0.0.0.0:9090,PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

I get an error that it can't listen on the meta-address 0.0.0.0.

This is currently being hosted with a public interface, but if I try to set this:

```
listeners=CLIENT://my.public.dns.name:9090,PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=CLIENT://my.public.dns.name:9090,PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

Then I get an error that it can't bind to the requested address. This is sitting behind some networking infrastructure, as it's obvious `ip addr` only shows my private IP address.

How would I get around this to setup a listener so an external/public producer/consumer could connect to this broker?

Thank you in advance!